# How to define custom attributes for nginx cookbook?

Tags: nginx, chef-infra, configuration-management, test-kitchen

For my current problem I'm using the `nginx`cookbook. What I want to do is to install it from source (no problem to do that using `nginx::source`) and prefix it to `/opt/nginx/<version>/`, but it will always be prefixed (by default) to `/opt/nginx-<version>/`.

This is my `./attributes/default.rb`:

```
node.override['nginx']['source']['prefix'] = "/opt/nginx/#{node['nginx']['source']['version']}"
#also tested
override['nginx']['source']['prefix'] = "/opt/nginx/#{node['nginx']['source']['version']}"
#and also
default['nginx']['source']['prefix'] = "/opt/nginx/#{node['nginx']['source']['version']}"
```

What am I not understanding?

Thanks

---

An additional thing would be:
 - How may I prefix it like above and create a sym-link to `/opt/nginx/current` (and do that even after update)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is a shortcoming in the cookbook.  Many variables are being built based on the value of that one attribute, and if you haven't set your override value FIRST, then the values in the cookbook will still win for the derived attributes.

If you set an override on the node or environment for `nginx['source']['prefix']` that should work, but it's not ideal.  Alternately, also override the derived values.

https://github.com/miketheman/nginx/blob/master/attributes/source.rb

```
default['nginx']['source']['sbin_path'] = "#{node['nginx']['source']['prefix']}/sbin/nginx"
default['nginx']['source']['default_configure_flags'] = %W(
  --prefix=#{node['nginx']['source']['prefix']}  # <= this one needs overridden
  --conf-path=#{node['nginx']['dir']}/nginx.conf
  --sbin-path=#{node['nginx']['source']['sbin_path']}
)
```

There may be others, but those are the two I know of, and that stand out.

Comment: IIRC Another way is to force re-evaluation of the original attribute file in the wrapper by using `include_attribute` ([Documentation here](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-file-ordering))

Comment: I've only tested with chefspec, so I could be mistaken, but I'm pretty sure that an attributes file will only be evaluated once, much like a recipe.  So if you use `include_attribute` but the attributes file has already been processed, it will be skipped.  But I'd love to be proven wrong on that one.

Comment: I started with If I remember correctly for that, I'm quite unsure of this.

Comment: Yep.  Sorry if I came off defensive.  I honestly hope you're right.  You may recall that the last time I disagreed with one of your IIRC's because of a test I wrote in ChefSpec, I was wrong.  :)

Comment: There's no offense and no need to be sorry ;) Indeed some times chefspec have different behaviors due to it's 'mocking' of providers, I'm pretty sure there's nothing special on attributes, but I may be wrong too. I'll try to test later